# How to make 3 vertical dots using CSS?

Tags: css

I want to have 3 dots on my page to, for example, toggle the display of a contextual menu. How can I achieve this using CSS?

[image: 3-dots toggle animation gif]

Comment: why can't you just use the html list tags? Why does it have to be only css?

Comment: I just need the bullets and not the text. On click of three dots a popover menu should popup

Comment: @user4903904 I wish I could upvote once more just for the great gif animation!

Answer (score 139, accepted):

using an unicode char

```css
.test:after {
  content: '\2807';
  font-size: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

using background property

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, black 10px, transparent 11px);
    background-size: 100% 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

shadow

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0px 40px 0px black, 0px 80px 0px black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

pseudo elements

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div:before, div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  }

div:before {
  top: 40px;
  }


div:after {
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 39):

Try this complete source code for 3 dot menu:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Three Dot Menu</title>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <style>
                *{margin: 0;padding:0px}

                .header{
                    width: 100%;
                    background-color: #0d77b6 !important;
                    height: 60px;
                }

                .showLeft{
                    background-color: #0d77b6 !important;
                    border:1px solid #0d77b6 !important;
                    text-shadow: none !important;
                    color:#fff !important;
                    padding:10px;
                }

                .icons li {
                    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
                    height: 7px;
                    width: 7px;
                    line-height: 0;
                    list-style: none outside none;
                    margin-right: 15px;
                    margin-top: 3px;
                    vertical-align: top;
                    border-radius:50%;
                    pointer-events: none;
                }

                .btn-left {
                    left: 0.4em;
                }

                .btn-right {
                    right: 0.4em;
                }

                .btn-left, .btn-right {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0.24em;
                }

                .dropbtn {
                    background-color: #4CAF50;
                    position: fixed;
                    color: white;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    border: none;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

                .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
                    background-color: #3e8e41;
                }

                .dropdown {
                    position: absolute;
                    display: inline-block;
                    right: 0.4em;
                }

                .dropdown-content {
                    display: none;
                    position: relative;
                    margin-top: 60px;
                    background-color: #f9f9f9;
                    min-width: 160px;
                    overflow: auto;
                    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                    z-index: 1;
                }

                .dropdown-content a {
                    color: black;
                    padding: 12px 16px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    display: block;
                }

                .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

                .show {display:block;}

            </style>
            <script>
                function changeLanguage(language) {
                    var element = document.getElementById("url");
                    element.value = language;
                    element.innerHTML = language;
                }

                function showDropdown() {
                    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
                }

                // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
                window.onclick = function(event) {
                    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
                        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                        var i;
                        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="header">

                <!-- three dot menu -->
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <!-- three dots -->
                    <ul class="dropbtn icons btn-right showLeft" onclick="showDropdown()">
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- menu -->
                    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#home">Home</a>
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 10):

Unicode includes ⠇ which is the Braille symbol for the letter "U". To use, just use the HTML entity `&#10247;` in your code.

Comment: This is a bad answer because it will not necessarily produce, as OP requires, ellipsis dots. On my Firefox Linux, for example, it produces 3 *squares*. If you really want to use Unicode, despite the inconsistency of cross-platform rendering, you should at least use VERTICAL ELLIPSIS '⋮', which would be more likely to yield dots than squares (and also has no risk of screwing with blind people/screenreaders by abusing Braille).

Comment: @gwern The squares is likely because you are missing a required font. With that said, yes, you make three good points: 1) Unicode fonts and support are still not where they should be, so not everyone is going to have the Braille fonts on their system 2)  While highly unlikely, there is a chance it may cause issues with people's screen readers. 3) Vertical ellipsis `&#8942;` is from Unicode 1.1 so would have much better support than the one I posted.

Comment: 'Required' by whom or what, exactly? I *do* have a font for that, which is why I see 3 squares instead of the Unicode tofu where no font is available... The problem here is one making assumptions about how the glyph will be rendered, assuming that how one's local font does it is how everyone else's font will do it. It's Braille, it doesn't have to be rendered as dots - it doesn't even have to be rendered as 3 shapes, it could be a grid, among other alternatives I see when googling 'Braille fonts'.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using font-awesome, it is as easy as including the `.fa-ellipsis-v`  style. Further documentation is found here: http://fontawesome.io/icon/ellipsis-v/.

Comment: font-awesome vertical dots are so ugly (and squared)!! cf accepted unicode solution for proper style

Answer (score 6):

Most voted answer showed me with dotted with 2 column, So I accomplished with below Unicode character.

```
<div>&#xFE19;</div>
```

︙

Answer (score 3):

1. With fontawesome.css

   ```
   <i class='fa fa-ellipsis-v'></i>
   ```
2. With Glyphicons

   ```
   <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-option-vertical"></span>
   ```
3. With css

   ```
   .textSpan:after {
    content: '\2807';
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #2e2e2e
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="dot"></div>
```

**css:**

```
.dot{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This appeared in the low quality review queue, most likely because you've given a code-only answer. I recommend including an explanation and reasoning behind your answer so that others can truly understand how and why this answers the quesiton.

Comment: Your css is  giving single dot. so i need to call this div for three times to achieve this. Can i have a single css which will give 3 dots, so i can call div at one time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link></script>

 <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v col-2 mt-3 .text-light fa-lg" style={{"float":"right"}}></i>
```

This can be used to see three dots.This can be used in cards in react